# ZF2 How to get access to the service manager on a custom class that is no a controller, helper or service

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

guys, 
At this point i am close to start pulling hair out of my head. I don't find a way to achieve this.

I have a custom class that belongs to a custom folder i created under my WebServices Module src folder. I need to be able to instantiate this class from inside another module/controller but when i do that and dump the services member it contains null.
How can i have the service manager accesible from inside my ApiAuthentication class.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<?php

namespace WebServices\Services;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ApiAuthenticationService extends \Zend\Soap\Client implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{

    public $services;

    function __construct($options = null){

        parent::__construct('http://tinysoa.local/soap/security/api_authentication?wsdl',$options);

    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->services = $locator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

}
```

When i call this from inside another module/controller it dumps a null value:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

       public function indexAction()
            {
                $a = new \WebServices\Services\ApiAuthenticationService();

                var_dump($a->services);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Responding with my own answer to add-on to Adrian's, and the question you asked in response.

If your service has dependencies of it's own, you just use a factory instead of going the invokable route.

Say your service needs a cache adapter and database adapter.  Also imagine that it can optionally be configured with some other service (FooService, below):

```
<?php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'my_service' => function($sm){
                $cache = $sm->get('Cache');
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('DefaultDbAdapter');
                $fooService = $sm->get('FooService');

                // instantiate your service with required dependencies
                $mySvc = new \My\Shiny\Service($cache, $dbAdapter);

                // inject an optional dependency
                $mySvc->setFooService($fooService);

                // return your shiny new service
                return $mySvc;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Side Note:  It's generally bad design to inject the ServiceManager all over the place.  You're better off managing your dependencies more explicitly, like above.

This stuff is covered quite well in the [Quick Start](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html), if you haven't already read that.

Answer (score 1):

Register your Service in Service Config and access it through getServiceLocator() method in controller.

Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
  return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'my_service' => 'WebServices\Services\ApiAuthenticationService'
    )
  );
}
```

Controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my_service');
}
```

Comment: That worked great. But i am wondering if there is other solution, because with this one the object is instantiated when i access to it through the service locator, but i need to pass parameters to the objects constructor. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters. Take a look at timdev's solution.